# Run 'rng-tools' in OpenVZ container

Tags: linux, openvz, random-number-generator

I have a problem with run 'rngd' inside OpenVZ container:

`root@server:~# rngd -r /dev/urandom
unable to adjust write_wakeup_threshold: Permission denied`

Is it possible to run an application in another way?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

There's only a single kernel in an OpenVZ system, so you would have to run rngd on the host node.